# Copy Tables and FileGroups from old database to new database

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2017

Using SSMS in SQL Server 2017, I need to copy a set of tables from a legacy database into a new database on the same server (my localhost).  The catch is that in the legacy database, when I script out the creation of some tables, they are created on a filegroup:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Foobar](
    [FoobarId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [OtherColumn] [varchar](100) NOT NULL) ON [AdvantagePrimary]
```

And when I run the script, of course, I get:

> Invalid filegroup 'AdvantagePrimary' specified.

There are ~100+ tables and 14 filegroups I am scripting over to the new database (I need all the schema plus the table constraints, indexes, triggers, etc).

So my question is... Is it possible to copy over (with a script or otherwise) both the Tables and the FileGroups? The accepted answer here ([Is it possible to copy a filegroup from one database to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421693/is-it-possible-to-copy-a-filegroup-from-one-database-to-another)) seems to say "Nope. You are SOL." I hope he's wrong.

I knew it was a long shot, but I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO  NewDatabase.sys.filegroups
SELECT * FROM LegacyDatabase.sys.filegroups
```

And got:

> Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: I'm not affiliated in any way but redgate has very good and affordable tools to do this.  It is rare it is not cost effective to get them.

Comment: @Hogan ok thanks. I will explore and make a case to the boss :)

Comment: https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/

Comment: @Hogan,  Thanks. I've downloaded the free sample. There were some bugs in the script it generated. And I'm not seeing how to copy filegroups.

Comment: I've never found them to have bugs -- just not knowing how to use the tool.  The support is super responsive, if there is an SQL Server feature it does not copy I'm sure they will explain.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just creating the filegroups manually in the target database. There were only 14 of them, so it wasn't too bad.  Found instructions on how to do this here:

https://codingsight.com/moving-existing-table-from-primary-filegroup-to-different-filegroup/

[image]